# App loading is too slow while adding images

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview

In my app , its a simple image Displaying app **In which i can add multiple images from external storage**

while adding images its takes too long to add the images and also sometimes an error occur that `OutOfMemory`.

how to solve this .Help please!!!

here is the some codes....

My **ImageCollection** Activity

```
public class ImageCollection extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String IMAGE_SHARED_PREFS = "com.example.animproject_IMAGE_SHARED_PREFS";
public static final String IMAGE_DATA_KEY = "com.example.animproject_IMAGE_DATA_KEY";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageCollectionAdapter adapter;
List<ImageModelClass> imageList;
FloatingActionButton fab;
String imageStringConvert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_collection);

    loadAlbumData();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.imageCollectionRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    adapter = new ImageCollectionAdapter(imageList, ImageLoader.getInstance(), imageStringConvert);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            gallery.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}

public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        assert data != null;
        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

        if (clipData != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                Uri imageUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                InputStream inputStream;

                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    ImageModelClass imageModelClass = new ImageModelClass();
                    imageStringConvert = encodeTobase64(bitmap);

                    imageModelClass.setImage(imageStringConvert);

                    imageList.add(imageModelClass);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    saveGalleryData();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } else {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                assert imageUri != null;
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageStringConvert = encodeTobase64(bitmap);

            ImageModelClass imageModelClass = new ImageModelClass();
            imageModelClass.setImage(imageStringConvert);

            imageList.add(imageModelClass);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            saveGalleryData();
        }
    }
}

private void saveGalleryData() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(IMAGE_SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(imageList);
    editor.putString(IMAGE_DATA_KEY, json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadAlbumData() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(IMAGE_SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ImageModelClass>>() {
    }.getType();
    String data = preferences.getString(IMAGE_DATA_KEY, null);
    imageList = gson.fromJson(data, type);

    if (imageList == null) {
        imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

}

And Here is Adapter class...

```
public class ImageCollectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageCollectionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

List<ImageModelClass> list;
ImageLoader loader;
String imageStringConvert;

public ImageCollectionAdapter(List<ImageModelClass> list, ImageLoader loader, String imageStringConvert) {
    this.list = list;
    this.loader = loader;
    this.imageStringConvert = imageStringConvert;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.image_collection_lists, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageModelClass currentImage = list.get(position);

    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(currentImage.getImage(), 0);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
            .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RoundedImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryPicture);
       
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Scaled down image before set to ImageView in adapter

Comment: did you try to checkout loading image logic to another Thread?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what are you saying i'm new in this @Ilja Tomilovych  @M D

Comment: I searched more on internet about this problem but i didnt understand

Comment: `its a simple image storing app ` Ok. But where will you store those images to? That is unclear. You only told that you got them from external storage.

Comment: @blackapps i am storing those images  in a recyclerView .I have provided the code also in question

Comment: I would not call that an image storing app. You will only display some images.

Comment: yeah my bad . you are right

Comment: Further you should not build up an arraylist of bitmaps or base64 encoded bitmaps as that leads to memory problems. Just make an array list of the obtained uries. Then in your adapter load the image files using a thread. Scale the images down while loading. A lot of people will advice you to use an image loading library instead.

Comment: i did the same i load the images using a thread but still its slow

Comment: Using a thread is not enough. You should not make an arraylist of bitmaps or encoded bitmaps. I think you are still doing that.

Comment: @blackapps thanks dude now its fast but if i am selecting images less than 10 then only its fast . But when i am scrolling the recycler view its lagging .. How can i fixed it

Comment: @blackapps But why its crashing when i am running application again from start  .       " Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here! "      this error is coming when i'm not using encoded bitmap

Comment: Please rewrite your post and post the code you use now. Otherwise we dont know what you are doing. `List<ImageModelClass> imageList;` throw away that list. You need: `List<Uri> uriList;` instead.

Comment: @blackapps i posted new  updated question . you said to throw this `List<ImageModelClass> imageList` but how can i use  this `List<Uri> uriList`

Comment: Just put the obtained `imageUri`s in that list. Then start your recycleview and adapter with it. In onbind vieuwholder load the file in the view using a thread and an uri. You can throw away `encodeTobase64(Bitmap..` too. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raplace your onBindViewHolder with

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageModelClass currentImage = list.get(position);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(currentImage.getImage(), 0);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                 holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               }
            }
            
        }
    }).start();
   

}
```

Comment: Its worked dude. its fast but only when i select images less than 10.. also scrolling recycler view is lagging how to fix it

Comment: But why its crashing when i am running application again from start

Comment: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!   this error is coming

Answer (score 1):

try to load image in thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //load Image in onActivityResult
        }
    }).start();
```

also you can low the quality of image in Base64 encode

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,/*quality of image maximum is 100*/ 100, baos);
```

Comment: should i write whole method (onActivityResult) in Run() method @Yahya Alborene

Answer (score 0):

You can also use glide library
    `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0' annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'`

and add these line in onBindViewHolder

`Glide.with ( activity).load ( byteImg).placeholder ( R.drawable.imagePlacaeholder ).into ( imageView );`